# Extend the dimensions of a 2D array in eclipse using C programming

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2D array named **H_initial** (3 rows 3 cols) filled with binary values, zeros and ones. Now I need to extend the size of the 2D array **H_initial** to another 2D array **H_final** (i.e 6 rows 6 cols) by replacing zeros in **H_initial** with a 2*2 zero matrix and ones in **H_initial** with 2*2 identity matrix. 
I first created a 6*6 zero matrix and then tried to replace the '1' in **H_initial** with 2*2 identity matrix using the below code but i'm not getting the required output. I'm programming in C using Eclipse for windows. Also, I'm new to C programming and I don't have enough knowledge on pointers, dynamic memory allocation. Could someone help me here please.

```
#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 6

int main()
{
    int i,j,a,b,H_final[6][6];

    // Create a H_initial matrix of size (3x3)
    int H_initial[3][3]={{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
    printf("H_initial= \n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {

            printf("%d\t",H_initial[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Create a zero matrix of size (6*6)
    printf("H_final=\n");
    for(a=0; a<6; a++)
    {
        for(b=0; b<6; b++)
        {
            H_final[a][b] = 0;
            printf("%d\t",H_final[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   

    // Create H_final by replacing 1 with 2*2 identity matrix
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(H_initial[i][j]==1)
            {
                for(m=0;m<2;m++)
                {
                    for(n=0;n<2;n++)
                    {
                        if(m==n)
                        {
                            H_final[2*i+m][2*j+n]=1;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: It would help if you clarified your question and code.  I *think* you have `H_initial` declared as 3x3 and `H_final` declared as 6x6, and are trying to fill in a 2x2 square of `H_final` for each single element of `H_initial`... but it's hard to tell from the wording, and your code doesn't show the declarations.

Comment: If `H_final` starts as a zero matrix, then for each element of `H_initial`, I think you just need `if (H_initial[i][j]) H_final[2*i][2*j] = H_final[2*i+1][2*j+1] = 1;`

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my code now. Yes, I have to do the exact same thing that you have mentioned in your comment  _"I think you have H_initial declared as 3x3 and H_final declared as 6x6, and are trying to fill in a 2x2 square of H_final for each single element of H_initial''_

Comment: Code is missing the declaration for `H_final`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with the inner loops:

```
            for(m=0;m<1;m++)
            {
                for(n=0;n<1;n++)
                {
                    if(m==n)
                    {
                        H_final[2*i+m][2*j+n)]=1;
                    }
                }

            }
```

would *almost* work, except that your loops only count from 0 to 0 so you only access the top-left element of the 2x2 square.  If you use eg. `for(m=0; m<2; m++)` and `for(n=0; n<2; n++)` that should fix it.  You also have a stray `)` to remove in the loop body where you access `H_final`.

It's overly complicated, though, since you can do the same thing with a one-liner without those inner loops:

```
            H_final[2*i][2*j] = H_final[2*i+1][2*j+1] = 1;
```

Comment: One-liner is working. Thanks a lot :) My bad, the indexing should be from m < 2 but I was doing some workaround and forgot to put it back. And I'm sorry I couldn't upvote this post as I'm new to stackoverflow and have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: However I can't generalize this formula for a nxn square. I tried `H_final[3*i][3*j] = H_final[3*i+1][3*j+1] = 1;` The first two diagonal entries are 1, but the third diagonal element is still 0. It would be great if you could please tell me how to generalize this formula for a nXn square.

Comment: Thanks but how can I generalize it in case of nXn square. I am using something like this `for(m=0;m<N;m++)
            {
                for(n=0;n<N;n++)
                {
                    if(m==n)
                    {
                        H_final[2*i+m][2*j+n]=1;
                    }
                }

            }` This works but this looks quite complicated. Could you please suggest an idea to reduce this to a simpler form without using multiple loops?

Comment: @shannon For NxN square, with `i` and `j` coords in original array:  `for (k=0; k<N; k++) H_final[N*i + k][N*j + k] = 1;` -- just one inner loop (sets column k of row k of the subsquare to 1 on each pass).